# Using Ubuntu 22.04.3 and a Archer T4UHP as an access point

Tags: wireless

I have an Ubuntu box which is connected to the internet over Ethernet.

I have a Archer T4UHP connected to it by USB. Usually, this would be used as a wi-fi adapter. Instead, I want to use it as an access point.

Is this possible? How would I do this?

Comment: Please edit to include results from terminal for `lsusb` and what driver is used